# Extract surrounding XML Tags by child content

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing

I have an XML file that basically looks like this:

```
<products xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Product Id="1">
      <Product Id="1_1">
        <Attribute Name="Whatever"></Attribute>
      </Product>
      <Attribute Name="Identifier">NumberOne</Attribute>
  </Product>
  <Product Id="2">
      <Attribute Name="Identifier">NumberTwo</Attribute>
  </Product>
</products>
```

What I want to do is to extract the complete products. Product Node by searching for

```
<Attribute Name="Identifier">SEARCH_TEXT</Attribute>
```

So for example, for NumberOne I would get the surrounding Product (Id="1") tags and their content.

Example: for the search text "NumberOne" the desired result is:

```
<Product Id="1">
      <Product Id="1_1">
        <Attribute Name="Whatever"></Attribute>
      </Product>
      <Attribute Name="Identifier">NumberOne</Attribute>
  </Product>
```

for the search text "NumberTwo" it would be

```
<Product Id="2">
      <Attribute Name="Identifier">NumberTwo</Attribute>
  </Product>
```

What I tried is this regex (Python):

```
<Product ((?!</Product>)[\S|\s])*<Attribute Name=\"Identifier\">NumberOne</Attribute>((?!</Product>)[\S|\s])*</Product>
```

But this does dot work because of the nested Products.
Does anyone have a hint for solving this?

I read that regex is not the smartest approach for these kinds of XML searching problems.
In reality the topLevel Products are weigh more complex, and I need to merge two XML files that look like my example.
So I was hoping by using regex I could solve this on "string" level rather than on XML Parser level where I might need to prepare those complex objects before generating the final XML output. Just find the topLevel Product by that Identifier value, and grab them completely - no matter what they contain otherwise.

Thanks a lot.

UPDATE:
Based on Jack Fleeting's solution - this is what I ended up using (XPath):

```
//products//Product[Attribute[@Name="Identifier" and text()="NumberOne"]]
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear: what **exactly** is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry - I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed not a good idea to try to parse xml with regex. Using xpath should get you there, assuming I understand you correctly. For example,

```
//Product[.//*[.="NumberOne"]]
```

should output:

```
<Product Id="1">
      <Product Id="1_1">
        <Attribute Name="Whatever"/>
      </Product>
      <Attribute Name="Identifier">NumberOne</Attribute>
  </Product>
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! 
Your suggestion would return a result if NumberOne would be a value in any child node of the product.
It works as you said - but is it possible to make sure that exactly this hierarchy is considered? 

To Check:
products.Product.Attribute[Name==Identifier] == NumberOne

To return:
products.Product

Comment: never mind:
I think this is what I needed:

//products//Product[Attribute[@Name="Identifier" and text()="NumberOne"]]

Thanks a lot!!